# How can I force one single refresh rate across both my monitors

Tags: nvidia, xorg, monitor

I have to different but similar monitors.

According to `nvidia-settings` my main monitor is running at 59.93 HZ while the other runs at 59.88 HZ.

In X Video settings I have enabled VSync and that it should sync to my primary monitor. This results in video tearing on my secondary.

Is there a way to specify a refresh rate at which both monitors should run?

[image: NVIDIA-setings]

Comment: I think you mean Hz, not MHz...

Comment: indeed, you are right.

Comment: What happens if you set them both manually to 60Hz? You have to first change the resolution from Auto, then set the refresh rate.

Comment: @Tom Brossman , where would I do that in the Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start up the NVIDIA control panel, called 'NVIDIA X Server Settings'

That brings up a window like this:

[image: NVIDIA Settings window]

Yours will look different, but the instructions are the same.

1. Click on 'X Server Display Configuration'(top left).
2. Go down to 'Resolution:'(bottom right).
3. The first item is 'Auto'. **Change that manually to your native resolution**. After doing this note that you can now change the refresh rate. (refresh rate can't be changed with resolution set to 'Auto')
4. Change the refresh rate to 60Hz, like shown in the image.
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 for the second monitor.
6. Save and quit, you should now have set the refresh rate manually to the same value for both monitors.

Comment: thank you for your reply Tom but unfortunately that's not an option for twin view because it's grayed out i.e. unchangeable, see http://imgur.com/Ehy8g

Comment: @ChristianSmorra Sorry that didn't work. Have you tried editing your [xorg.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/xorg.conf.5.html) file directly? It's in /etc/X11. There may be a good reason you can't access the setting, so make sure you **back up your old file and understand how to restore it with no GUI** if things go wrong.

Comment: @ChristianSmorra I just looked at your screenshot and Resolution: is set to 'Auto'. You did try setting it manually, right? It is supposed to be greyed out until you manually set the resolution, (see steps 3 & 4 of my answer above).

Comment: thanks Tom, appreciate your help! By setting the resolution manually I could change the refresh rate to 60 HZ and the tearing is gone.

Comment: @ChristianSmorra Glad to help. I've edited my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: note that I also hardcoded horizontal and vertical sync to 60.0 in my xorg.conf so that might have done the trick too